# Why the downloaded image shows that it appears that we don't support this file format

Tags: javascript, file-handling, imagedownload

I'm hosted a static html file on netlify here is the url...
https://laughing-lewin-eb42f8.netlify.app/

I'm successfully download the images when I trying to open it it show that **it appears that we don't support this file format**

I didn't understand why it's happening and can anyone tell me please how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your image links are incorrectly defined in the script with a spurious https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ in front of them:-

```
 if (v == 1) {
                var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital-windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg';
            } else if (v == 2) {
                var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/694/526/541/digital-art-illustration-women-window-wallpaper-preview.jpg';
            } else if (v == 3) {
                var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/230/886/355/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-hobbit-bag-end-the-shire-wallpaper-preview.jpg';
            } else {
                var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/471/818/383/life-house-architecture-building-wallpaper-preview.jpg';
```

Comment: then how can I define the url because if I give url without https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com then it's throw cors error and also I did not access server side to set Access Control Allow Origin so how can I do that....

Comment: Whats a cors error sorry??

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error , Access Control Allow Origin error